# How is fetching parameters of a child different than fetching a child without parameters?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I changed it so that a child has multiple parameters(image and caption) instead of just being an image child.

This is what I have as relevant code.

```
class MyUser {
    var UserFirstName: String?
    var PhotoPosts: String?
    init(UserFirstName: String?, Photos: String?) {
        self.Photos = Photos
        self.UserFirstName = UserFirstName
    }
}

var peeps = [MyUser]()

public override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell

    let image1 = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView

    let person: MyUser = peeps[indexPath.row]


    cell.lblName.text = person.UserFirstName

    if let Photos = person.Photos {
        let url = URL(string: Photos)
        image1.sd_setImage(with: url)
    }

    return cell

}
```

And

```
musicians.observe(DataEventType.value,  with: {snapshot in

    for peeps in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
        if peeps.key != thisUsersUid {
            let peepsObject = people.value as? [String: AnyObject]
            let peepsUserFirstName = peopleObject?["UserFirstName"] as? String
            let peepsPhotos = peopleObject?["Photos"]  as? String
            let RAA = MyUsers(Photos: peepsPhotos, UserFirstName: peepsUserFirstName)
            self.peeps.append(RAA)

        }
        self.table.reloadData()
    }
}
```

I'd like it to fetch the image parameter of the child and not look for the image only behind the child reference.

Comment: Try to add the full functions and not half the scope, it will be easier to understand what you are asking for

Comment: Sorry. I added only the bare bones because I thought it would be easier to have the focus on where the error is. I have now added the fuller version of code concerning this problem. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I formatted your question but actualy it is not really clear. What is it that you are trying to achieve exactly? what have you tried and whats not working?